# MySQL query with two INNER JOIN returns duplicate entries in the result

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates, distinct, inner-join

I have the following data structure: Articles have m:n Users

There are three tables: *articles*, *users* and **articles_users** (linking table)

Now I need this query: *Give me all Users who have recently written an Article*.

Unfortunately, this query returns duplicate results:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT users.id, 
        users.username, 
        articles.published, 
        articles_users.user_id
FROM    users 
        INNER JOIN articles_users 
            ON users.id = articles_users.user_id
        INNER JOIN articles     
            ON articles.id = articles_users.article_id
ORDER BY articles.published DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Result:

```
id      username        published   user_id
113     silva_mihat     2012-10-30  112
228     paula_tille     2012-10-27  258
228     paula_tille     2012-10-26  258
631     andrea_gurkow   2012-10-24  631
275     hubert_mayer    2012-10-24  275
198     annette_mulger  2012-10-22  198
255     uta_zuffter     2012-10-22  235
and so on ...
```

Does anyone have an idea why DISTINCT isn't working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should group by author instead of of by article.

```
select
  users.id,
  users.username,
  maxPublished
from users
inner join (
  select
    max(articles.published) as maxPublished,
    articles_users.user_id as userID
  from articles
  join articles_users on articles_users.article_id = articles.id
  group by articles_users.user_id
) as p on users.id = userID
order by maxPublished desc
limit 25
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. An alternative solution would be this: `SELECT users.id, users.username, max(articles.published), articles_users.user_id FROM users INNER JOIN articles_users ON users.id = articles_users.user_id INNER JOIN articles ON articles_users.article_id = articles.id GROUP BY articles_users.user_id ORDER BY max(articles.published) DESC LIMIT 25`

Answer (score 1):

because `DISTINCT` applies to the whole row (*not just the  `users.id` itself*). as you can see all the rows returned are not *unique*. Try something like this, the idea behind the subquery is it gets the recent `published` date for each `article_id`

```
SELECT  users.id, 
        users.username, 
        articles.published
FROM    users 
        INNER JOIN articles_users 
            ON users.id = articles_users.user_id
        INNER JOIN articles 
            ON articles.id = articles_users.article_id
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT id, MAX(published) maxDate
            FROM articles
            GROUP BY id
        ) c ON  articles.id = c.ID AND 
                articles.published = c.maxDATE
-- ORDER BY articles.published DESC
-- LIMIT 25
```

Comment: A friend of mine just gave me this solution: `SELECT users.id, users.username, max(articles.published), articles_users.user_id
FROM users 
INNER JOIN articles_users ON users.id = articles_users.user_id
INNER JOIN articles ON articles_users.article_id = articles.id 
GROUP BY articles_users.user_id
ORDER BY max(articles.published) DESC 
LIMIT 25`

Comment: does it gives you exact result? maybe it will work for sometime, but if you want to add some specific columns eg (*articlename, or any.*) it will not give you correct result.

Comment: Yeah. Result is correct. All I want is "Give me all Users who have recently written an Article"

Comment: well, ok :D i was just giving the other way around..hehe